# Run protractor tests in Eclipse or Visual Studio

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, protractor

I'm new on protractor and i got a few tests running (i did in Webstorm 30 day trial). But now i'm trying to do it in Eclipse to integrate with TFS or VS itself, so i can associate with our test cases. Does anyone know how to? Do i have to use an especific IDE or something like that?

Comment: for Eclipse, see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459476/how-to-run-your-protractor-tests-in-eclipse?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio itself, you can write protractor tests (Protractor for .NET is built on top of Selenium WebDriver C# binding.) by installing protractor package and Nunit, then you can integrate with TFS if you want.
For more information, you can look into this [link](https://github.com/bbaia/protractor-net).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Eclipse Neon.
Probably yow will have to downgrade your protractor because it works only till 4.10(It doesn't work with latest version)