# How to run your protractor tests in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, protractor

I have installed Enide Studio 2014 from eclipse marketspace. What configurations setting need to be done in Eclipse to make protractor tests running.

Currently I am using Webstorm IDE and it has run configurations setting like Node Interpreter, Working Directory, JavaScript File, Application parameters.

I am not not sure where I can do the same settings in Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer I'm the author of [AngularJS Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started)

I suggest you that you install [AngularJS Eclipse 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Installation-Update-Site) which provides now an [Eclipse Protractor support](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Protractor) :

- **completion, hyperlink, validation** for Protractor in the JavaScript Editor
- **Run/Debug Protractor**

[image: Debug protractor with Eclipse]

Comment: I've tried 1.2.0 snaps version in my eclipse Mars 2 but i don't see run as protractor option though

Comment: Have you convert yoru project to AngularJS Eclipse?

Comment: I have converted it to tern project as suggested here: https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-Protractor-support

Comment: Have you too selected in Tern modules angular tern plugin?

Comment: Got it..so I had selected only protractor in the modules and not angularJS now I can see..Thanks @Angelo